# Daloradius Users can't login DB error (MySQL)

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, radius, freeradius

I set up Freeradius with the Daloradius WebGUI to manage Users, NAS etc.. It works fine, I can login as admin, create users and those users can authenticate against the Radius Server (tested with radtest).

However the user login, that allows users to change their password, accessed via
http://domain.com/daloradius/daloradius-users/login.php doesn't work.
When trying to login with a user account, I get the following error:

```
Database connection error
Error Message: DB Error: connect failed
```

I don't really get why, since the database connection obviously works, because I can login to the admin interface as admin. Has anyone an idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks for all replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this in my own research for the solution.

There is another config file inside daloradius:

```
/var/www/html/daloradius/daloradius-users/library/daloradius.conf.php
```

and you have to setup the file with the database information.

Then when you setup the users, under "User Info", Check "Enable User Portal Login" and set a password for them.